# Binding value to not first argument

Tags: haskell, currying

I have a class named "Person"

```
Person :: String -> String -> Int -> Gender -> Person
```

**Goal:**
To make a more general version of Person, the femalePerson by assigning Gender to Female.

**What works:**
Binding first N elements works:

```
let personsWithNameAlice = Person "Alice"
let personsWithNameAliceMcGee = Person "Alice" "McGee"
```

**What doesn't work:**

```
let femalePerson = Person {gender = Female}
```

**Question:**

- How do i do THIS?
- How do i a bind a value to n-th element of any function where n != 0?

It's just that i know i can write f(x,y,z) = g(x,y,z,5) in math and std::bind2nd(f, 8) in C++ so shouldn't it be possible in Haskell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with a lambda expression, given

```
Person :: String -> String -> Int -> Gender -> Person
```

you'd define

```
femalePerson = \fn ln a -> Person fn ln a Female
```

or, with arguments in the binding:

```
femalePerson fn ln a = Person fn ln a Female
```

If you want to bind specifically the second parameter, `flip` is the function you want

```
third = flip (/) 3
```

You can use `flip` to bind arguments in arbitrary positions, but that quickly becomes a hassle and unreadable:

```
femalePerson = curry . curry $ flip (uncurry (uncurry Person)) Female
```

Comment: Thanks. I would be extra happy if Haskell allowed {paramName = value} syntax to be used for binding but that will do as well.

Answer (score 13):

Use [semantic editor combinators](http://conal.net/blog/posts/semantic-editor-combinators).
For instance, suppose you have a function:

```
foo :: Int -> String -> Bool -> Char -> Float
foo = undefined
```

I've changed the example to involve all distinct types, so type checking will ensure we have our definitions right.
We want the following four kinds of specializations, each resulting from filling in one argument:

```
foo0 ::        String -> Bool -> Char -> Float  -- 3
foo1 :: Int ->           Bool -> Char -> Float  -- "hey"
foo2 :: Int -> String ->         Char -> Float  -- True
foo3 :: Int -> String -> Bool ->         Float  -- 'x'
```

The first one is easy, being straight partial application:

```
foo0 = foo 3
```

However, let's write it in an odd way (for consistency with the others):

```
foo0 = ($ 3) foo
```

For the others, use `result`, which is a synonym for composition:

```
result :: (b -> b') -> ((a -> b) -> (a -> b'))
result = (.)
```

An application of `result` aims a given function on the "result" of another function (and so is directly analogous to the `first` and `second` functions from `Control.Arrow`).
Repeated applications then aim inside multiple results, skipping past successive curried arguments, exactly as we need:

```
foo1 = result ($ "hey") foo
foo2 = (result.result) ($ True) foo
foo3 = (result.result.result) ($ 'x') foo
```

Note that the nth specialization uses `result` composed with itself n times.